# How to combine columns with dummy variables in pandas (one output)?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

Given the following data frame and dummy variables. How does one combine or collapse two or more columns to create a new column that has either 1 if one or more col has a 1, or 0 if NONE of the cols had a 1.

```
data = {'cat_1': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], 'cat_2':[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'cat_3':[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'cat_4':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data, index=['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'])
df

   cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  cat_4
s1      1      1      0      1
s2      0      0      0      1
s3      1      0      1      1
s4      1      1      1      0
s5      0      1      1      0
```

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
data2 = {'cat_1_cat_2 combined': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'cat_3_cat_4 combined':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
new_df=pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'])
print(new_df)

    cat_1_cat_2 combined  cat_3_cat_4 combined
s1                     1                     1
s2                     0                     1
s3                     1                     1
s4                     1                     1
s5                     1                     1
```

Comment: Just use `|`, e.g to combine `cat1` and `cat2`, `(df.cat_1 | df.cat_2).astype(int)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to do this is the following:

Replace 0:s by `nan` in for instance `cat_2` and `cat_3`

```
df['cat_2'] = np.where(df['cat_2'],1,np.nan)
df['cat_4'] = np.where(df['cat_4'],1,np.nan)
```

which gives:

```
cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  cat_4
s1      1    1.0      0    1.0
s2      0    NaN      0    1.0
s3      1    NaN      1    1.0
s4      1    1.0      1    NaN
s5      0    1.0      1    NaN
```

and then combine them:

```
df["combined 1 and 2 "] = df.pop("cat_2").fillna(df.pop("cat_1")).astype(int)
df["combined 3 and 4 "] = df.pop("cat_4").fillna(df.pop("cat_3")).astype(int)
```

which return your expected df:

```
combined 1 and 2   combined 3 and 4 
s1                  1                  1
s2                  0                  1
s3                  1                  1
s4                  1                  1
s5                  1                  1
```

Alternatively,

```
df['combined 1 and 2'] = (df.cat_1 | df.cat_2).astype(int)
df['combined 3 and 4'] = (df.cat_3 | df.cat_4).astype(int)
df = df.drop(['cat_1','cat_2','cat_3','cat_4'], axis =1)
```